# DIV mysteriously moving down

Tags: html, css

I am designing a header and my text div is moving down.

HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang = "en-AU">
    <head>
        <title>Simon Teacher Search</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <base href="../">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/desktop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "body-container">
            <header id = "header">
                <div id = "header-content">
                    <div id = "logo-container">
                        <img src = "Images/SHCK Logo.png" alt = "SHC Logo">
                    </div>
                    <div id = "header-text-container">
                        <div id = "header-text-top-container">
                            <span id = "SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE">SACRED HEART COLLEGE</span>
                            <span id =""></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id = "header-text-bottom-container">
                            <span id = "Kyneton">Kyneton</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    /*Code written by Oliver Murfett and Caelan Grgurovic 2015
Start Code*/

/*The following are classes that can be added to tags to give them certain features*/

.italics, i, em {
    font-style: italic;
}

.bold, b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.underline, u {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

/*Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans-Regular";
    src: url(Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Trajan Pro Regular";
    src: url(Fonts\Trajan Pro Regular.ttf);
}
/*The following styles are to the maximize page space*/
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#body-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px;

}

/*The following styles are to style the header*/

#header-content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box;    
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#logo-container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#logo-container img {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#header-text-container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

#header-text-top-container {
    height: 50%;
    min-height: 50;
}

#header-text-bottom-container {
    height: 50%;
    min-height: 50;
}

#SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE {
    font-family: "Trajan Pro Regular";
    font-size: 34px;
    color: rgb(30,30,117);
}
```

All code here: http://jsfiddle.net/j5kcfwLa/

Now for my problem: The #header-text-container div is moving down and not staying to the top. I have tried `top: 0;`, which does nothing, and `position: absolute`, which makes unnecessary chances. How can I force this container to the top of its parent?

Comment: why dont you try like this http://jsfiddle.net/j5kcfwLa/2/

Comment: @Oliver Murfett you just missed to apply 'px' or '%' after 50 in following selector  #header-text-bottom-container {
 height: 50%;
 min-height: 50;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
#SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE {
    font-family:"Trajan Pro Regular";
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb(30, 30, 117);
}
```

to this:

```
#SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE {
    font-family:"Trajan Pro Regular";
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb(30, 30, 117);

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/j5kcfwLa/1/)

Comment: @Your welcome. Please mark the question as resolves if this is teh answer you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to achieve like up user have said then you can try by just adding

```css
#SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE {
    font-family: "Trajan Pro Regular";
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb(30,30,117);
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

hey are you trying to achieve this.?

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5kcfwLa/3/)

```css
/*Code written by Oliver Murfett and Caelan Grgurovic 2015
Start Code*/

/*The following are classes that can be added to tags to give them certain features*/

.italics, i, em {
 font-style: italic;
}

.bold, b, strong {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.underline, u {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}

/*Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans-Regular";
    src: url(Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Trajan Pro Regular";
    src: url(Fonts\Trajan Pro Regular.ttf);
}
/*The following styles are to the maximize page space*/
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: white;
 top: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

#body-container {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 height: 100px;
 
}

/*The following styles are to style the header*/

#header-content {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
 box-sizing: border-box;    
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

#logo-container {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

#logo-container img {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

#header-text-container {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

#header-text-top-container {
 height: 50%;
 min-height: 50;
}

#header-text-bottom-container {
 height: 50%;
 min-height: 50px;
}

#SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE {
 font-family: "Trajan Pro Regular";
 font-size: 24px;
 color: rgb(30,30,117);
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div id = "body-container">
   <header id = "header">
    <div id = "header-content">
     <div id = "logo-container">
      <img src = "Images/SHCK Logo.png" alt = "SHC Logo">
     </div>
     <div id = "header-text-container">
      <div id = "header-text-top-container">
       <span id = "SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE">SACRED HEART COLLEGE</span>
       <span id =""></span>
      </div>
      <div id = "header-text-bottom-container">
       <span id = "Kyneton">Kyneton</span>
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: @Oliver Murfett please check out the answer